# What is pattern regex to remove a attribute but not the same value?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This is my text:

```
<Row ss:Height="16.8" ss:Width="100" > </Row><Row ss:Height="15"> </Row>
```

I want to remove all text: `ss:Height="?"`

Result: `<Row  ss:Width="100" > </Row><Row > </Row>`

I try this pattern `'ss:Height=".*"'` but it can't:

```js
var strXMLString = '<Row ss:Height="16.8" ss:Width="100" > </Row><Row ss:Height="15"> </Row>';
var strPattern = 'ss:Height=".*"';
reg = new RegExp(strPattern, "g");
strXMLString = strXMLString.replace(reg, "");
alert(strXMLString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you need to stop at first occurence using `(.*?)` so the regex would look like this :

```
ss:Height="(.*?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/wu7Eyq/1/

```js
var strXMLString = ' <Row ss:Height="16.8" ss:Width="100" > </Row><Row ss:Height="15"> </Row>';
var strPattern = 'ss:Height="(.*?)"';
reg = new RegExp(strPattern, "g");
strXMLString = strXMLString.replace(reg, "");
alert(strXMLString);
```

Comment: well, actually your solution is more elegant than mine ;)

Comment: @lbrutti I +1ed you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```js
const regex = /ss:Height="\d+\.?\d*"/gm;
const str = `<Row ss:Height="16.8" ss:Width="100" > </Row><Row ss:Height="15"> </Row>`;
strXMLString = str.replace(regex, "");
alert(strXMLString);
```

Comment: hmmm, why? can you give me a counter example? 
I assumed your attribute has only numeric values

Comment: a sample in my question.

Comment: hmmm, please try run the snippet, it seem doing what you need.